# Sorting sellers by gridview C#

Tags: c#, sorting

Im sorting a list of sellers through my dataGridView and everything seems to work fine as long as the numbers are 1-9 in amountSold. How do I increase those values?

Second problem is, when the sorting is done the amount of sellers in a specific sells volume should be typed out "Amount of sellers in level 4 is: "X". But I only get 1 seller in my label8 no mather what...

This is a school assigmnet so have comments in swedish for my teacher to read.

Only need to get the sorting done and then I have been experimenting on converting my DataTable to a List since everyting needs to be saved to a file.

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Här deklarerar jag min säljar class med respektive egenskaper.
            var salesman = new Salesman();

            // Deklarerar varibler som skall användas för mina text boxes.
            string name, securityNumber, district;
            int amountSold;

            int level;

            // Binder mina varibler till respektive textBox.
            name = txtName.Text;
            securityNumber = txtSecurity.Text;
            district = txtDistrict.Text;
            amountSold = int.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
            //level = int.Parse(Text);


            // Binder min säljar class egenskaper till mina variabler som är bundna till respektive textBox.
            salesman.Name = name;
            salesman.SecurityNumber = securityNumber;
            salesman.District = district;
            salesman.AmountSold = amountSold;
            //salesman.Level = level;
            
            // Skapar mitt kolumnsystem. Gör den även dynamisk så antalet säljare inte är begränsat.
            // Namnger mina kolumner.
            DataTable information = new DataTable();
            information.Columns.Add("Namn");
            information.Columns.Add("Personnummer");
            information.Columns.Add("Distrikt");
            information.Columns.Add("Antal artiklar");

            // Delegerar mina variabler till motsvarande kolumn. 
            DataRow row = information.NewRow();
            row["Namn"] = name;
            row["Personnummer"] = securityNumber;
            row["Distrikt"] = district;
            row["Antal artiklar"] = amountSold;
            information.Rows.Add(row);

            // Positionerar mina Cells i förhållande till mina variabler.
            foreach (DataRow Drow in information.Rows)
            { 
                int num = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[0].Value = Drow["Namn"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[1].Value = Drow["Personnummer"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[2].Value = Drow["Distrikt"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[3].Value = Drow["Antal artiklar"].ToString();
                
            }

            

            // Rensar mina textboxes för att hämta en ny säljare.
            txtName.Text = "";
            txtSecurity.Text = "";
            txtDistrict.Text = "";
            txtAmount.Text = "";

     

        }


        public void SalemansList()
        {
            // Konverterar om DataTable till List genom en Loop
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Salesman");
            dt.Columns.Add("Namn", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Personnummer", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Distrik", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Antal artiklar", typeof(string));


            List<Salesman> salelvls = new List<Salesman>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Salesman saleman = new Salesman();

                saleman.AmountSold = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Antal artiklar"]);
            }

          
        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var salesman = new Salesman();
            
            int lvlOneSalesman = 0;
            int lvlTwoSalesman = 0;
            int lvlThreeSalesman = 0;
            int lvlFourSalesman = 0;

            if (salesman.AmountSold < 50)
            {
                lvlOneSalesman++;
                label8.Text = lvlOneSalesman.ToString();
            }

            if (salesman.AmountSold >= 50 && salesman.AmountSold < 99)
            {
                lvlTwoSalesman++;
                label12.Text = lvlTwoSalesman.ToString(); 
            }

            if (salesman.AmountSold >= 100 && salesman.AmountSold < 199)
            {
                lvlThreeSalesman++;
                label13.Text = lvlThreeSalesman.ToString();
            }

            if (salesman.AmountSold >= 199)
            {
                lvlFourSalesman++;
                label14.Text = lvlFourSalesman.ToString();
            }

            // Sorterar kolumner utifrån plats 3 som är "Antal artiklar"
            this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns[3], ListSortDirection.Descending);

        }




    }   
        
}
```

Comment: make sure the type of column for the amount is a numeric type otheriwse it will order it like a string

Comment: If you have a DataTable you should same save to an XML file using dt.WriteXml(fileName).  You can sort using : dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("Antal artiklar")).CopyToDataTable();  To sort by number you shold change the DataColumn to a number :  information.Columns.Add("Personnummer",typeof(int));